# Tool for tracing C++ program execution

Tags: c++, debugging, trace

I recently read in a magazine that there is a new commercial developer tool for Windows which monitors a C++ program's execution and creates traces for visual inspection. I, however, cannot remember the tool's name (it is not Insure++ and also not BugTrapper). In the resulting trace, you see every code line that was visited, you can see in which order it happened, and you can see the call stack at any point in the lifetime of the program.

Does anyone know this tool's name or a similar tool?

Many thanks in advance

/Frank

Comment: I found the magazine article again: the tool I was looking for is called Software Diagnostics (http://www.softwarediagnostics.com). I will accept ttchong's answer, because GDB has a set of commands for program tracing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use GDB and I still love it.

Edit: Thanks for @T.E.D, it may be GPROF which report hits count on code line/segment visited.

Comment: I almost +1'd this, except it doesn't really answer the question ;)

Comment: @incrediman - GDB do the thing that the question is asking for.

Comment: No, the proper tool for what he is asking after is gprof, not gdb.

Comment: @T.E.D: By referring to debugger like Insure++ and BugTrappe. I guess he is asking for debugger instead of profiler. Anyway look again at the question "...see every code line that was visited...", it seem he is really asking for profiler instead. Kudos to you!

Comment: gprof produces *traces*?  I thought it produced profile data and perhaps dynamic call graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Similar tool: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 0):

AutomatedQA TestComplete, or AQTime